# how to load Scala jar to oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, scala

i tried `loadjava -force -resolve -user user/pass@dbname scala-library.jar`, but it failed with message:

```
errors   : class scala/App$$anonfun$main$1
    ORA-29534:   referenced object  scheme.scala/App could not be resolved
```

and many more other classes with same  ORA-29534

Purpose of all this: the use of programs written in scala from oracle stored procedure

upd: oracle 11, scala 2.10.0, java 1.6.39

Comment: Hi, from what I remember, Java support in Oracle DB is very limited. You can use your jars but everything it needs have to be packed within. And of course compiled to bytecode - *.class files. You probably have a dependency on some *.scala file in your code - try to run it in your local JVM first.

Comment: i tried it in intellij and it work. problems only with loading into oracle

Comment: Specify also resolver details. It works on 12c. Haven't tried on 11.2